# How to grant user User Points equal to certain field's value / calculated value?

Tags: drupal-7, flags, drupal-rules, userpoints

I've a content type 'Content' with the field 'Value' (an integer) and a flag called 'Publish Content and grant points to user'. Every time a **Content is flagged** with this flag, I'd like to **grant the Content's author some User Points, equal to the value in the 'Value' field**.

I tried solving the first part of my problem with the Rules module like this:

```
*Event: A node has been flagged, under "Publish Content and grant points to user"

*Conditions: Content is of type 'Content'

*Actions: Grant points to a user: ...
```

However, it's impossible to pick `flagged-node:field-value` in the Points section. I also tried:

```
*Event: A node has been flagged, under "Publish Content and grant points to user"

*Conditions: Content is of type 'Content'

*Actions:

 - Calculate a value: `[flagged-node:field-value]` "+" 0. (Variable name = result)

 - Grant points to a user: ...
```

But then, the variable 'result' is not available. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: So every time, when user click to flag on node, in rules must add +1 to field 'Value'?

Comment: No, the user who added the Content has to get the same amount of User Points as the 'Value' field. Only I, as administrator, can flag content. The value in the field 'Value' doesn't change after the flagging.

Comment: You can make 5 rules, each one be have condition:
'If value is 1 = grants 1', 'If value has 2 = grants 2'... 'If value has 5 = grants 5'

Comment: Okay, but that seems a lot of work (imagine that I'd like to grant up to 100 points or something...). I tried 'Calculate a value': flagged-node:field-value + 0, because that's of course equal to the value in the Value field. I called this result 'Result'. Unfortunately, I can't grant the author of the flagged Content 'Result' User Points... Or can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution! I completed the second scenario (the amount of User Points is calculated) successfuly! Apparently, the User Points module didn't know that the calculation was an integer. Therefore, I had to add an extra action **Convert data type**: *Target type: Integer, Value to convert: [result], Rounding behavior: Always down*. I called it 'total' and granted the user this amount of User Points.